# How to get in Python the path to a installed program in windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, exe

I'm writing a scritp in Python that calls Ghostscript in windows terminal.

I need to get the path where a program is installed in windows (e.g. Ghostcript)

There are any environment variable or any other method (system registry) to get the path?

**SOLUTION (from @abarnert answer:)**

```
    import winreg

    program_to_found = 'Software\\GPL Ghostscript'

    try:
        h_key = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, program_to_found)
        try:
            gs_version = winreg.EnumKey(h_key, 0)
            h_subkey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, program_to_found+'\\'+gs_version)
            gs_dll = (winreg.EnumValue(h_subkey,0))[1]
            print("Ghostscript %s is installed in: %s" % (gs_version, gs_dll.replace('gsdll32.dll', '')))
        except OSError:
            print("Ghostscript insn't correctly installed!! ")
    except PermissionError:
        print("Ghostsript not found!! ")
```

This works for winXP and win7 32bit system.

Comment: What do you need this for? If Ghostscript's path is on your `%PATH%`, you should be able to just run it as a bare name. If it's not (that is, you can't use it directly from a cmd window), Windows probably can't tell you in general. But… if Ghostscript has installed itself as a handler for, e.g., `.ps` file, you can search the registry for it that way. Or if it has any known registry entries that it always creates.

Comment: Ghostscript doesn't change the %PATH% in Win.  When I call Ghostscript I need to call it whit the full path, and I don't want to change the %PATH% of the users of my script.

Comment: OK, then there is no generic way to "get the path to an installed program". As implied by my previous comment, there are ways to get paths from file-type associations, .msi install records, etc., or of course anything custom that Ghostscript puts in the registry. But if a program has a custom .exe installer, doesn't create any file-type associations, and doesn't write anything to the registry, there's nothing to look up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is impossible *in general*. Windows can't find arbitrary installed programs. But it may be possible for any *particular* app, Ghostscript included.

Programs that were installed by the .msi mechanism or something else that interacts with the "uninstall" mechanism in Add/Remove Programs, you can find entries for that. But programs with their own custom installers and uninstallers don't have to do this.

Programs that add a "file type associations" (so that, e.g., if you double-click a `.ps` file Windows knows how to open it) can be found through those associations.

And of course many programs install their own arbitrary registry keys, and you can always search for those.

If you look at the [Ghostscript installation docs](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Install.htm#Install_Windows), it explains a little bit about what it does. I think the short version is:

- There's an option to add the directory that `GS.EXE` sits in to your `%PATH%`—but in your case, obviously, it isn't there.
- There's an option to register the path to `GS.EXE` as a file type association for at least `.ps` files, unless something else already owned it.
- The path to `GSDLL32.DLL` may be found in the `GS_DLL` environment variable, or in `HKCU\Software\GPL Ghostscript\#.##` or `HKLM\Software\GPL Ghostscript\#.##` (where that `#.##` is the major and minor version number). Of course there's no guarantee that the DLL and the EXE are in the same location (which is why it does all that complicated stuff in the first place).
- The path to the uninstaller is registered with the Windows uninstaller mechanism. Of course there's no guarantee that `GS.EXE` is in the same directory as the uninstaller.

Since almost all of these are optional, it comes down to how much effort you want to put into trying all the different possibilities.

To access these registry keys from Python, see the [`_winreg`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) module in the stdlib.

Comment: Then, how can I get HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript\#.## value from my Python script?

Comment: @Trimax: See the [`winreg`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) module. You will have to `CreateKey` the `GPL Ghostscript`, then `EnumKey` to find the right version number.

Comment: It's named the [`_winreg`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#module-_winreg) module in Python 2.

Comment: @martineau: Sorry, use my link, not my text. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get path to GhostScript bin folder this way:

```
from winreg import OpenKey, QueryValue, EnumKey, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, KEY_READ

def get_ghostscript_path():  # function returns Ghostscript bin folder path
        key = r'SOFTWARE\Artifex\GPL Ghostscript'
        sub_key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key, access=KEY_READ)
        return QueryValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, f'{key}\\{EnumKey(sub_key, 0)}') + r'\bin'
```